# why does Q.ninvoke return an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise, q

I wanted to simplify this method:

```
var Q = require('q');

module.exports.save = function (db, item) {
  return Q.promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    db.items.save(item, function (e, result) {
      if (e) {
        reject(e);
      } else if (result) {
        resolve(result);
      } else {
        reject('object expected');
      }
    });
  });
};
```

which worked fine and the promise returned an object from the database.

I replaced it with just

```
module.exports.save = function (db, item) {
  return Q.ninvoke(db.items, 'save', item);
};
```

which also works fine but resolves with an array with a single element and this element is the same as in the original code.

Why is it doing this? How to make it not put the result into an array?

Comment: Can you show us (link) the code of the `save` method that you're using?

Comment: @Bergi this is just calling a method in `mongodb`: https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs/blob/master/index.js#L269

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but resolves with an array with a single element

I don't think so. It should be an array of length 2, with the first element being the saved item(s) and the second being a "lastError" object. From the code of the `save` method:

```
if (err) return cb(err);
if (doc === 1) {
  cb(err, args[0], lastErrorObject);
} else {
  // The third parameter is a faked lastErrorObject
  cb(err, doc, { n : 0});
}
```

When the callback is called with no error and more than 1 result argument, `Q.ninvoke` automatically converts this into an array with which the promise is resolved (from [`makeNodeResolver`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v1/q.js#L603)):

```
function nodecallback(error, value) {
    if (error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
    } else if (arguments.length > 2) {
        deferred.resolve(array_slice(arguments, 1));
    } else {
        deferred.resolve(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting... thanks. how come the original method resolves with just an object?

Comment: I have no idea what exactly the `mongojs` library does there and where it gets the `lastErrorObject` from - I couldn't trace it down in the `mongodb-native` code at least.